# Considering only rows with certain value in a column in R

Tags: r, function, matrix

I have a matrix that looks like this

```
1 2 8 
2 2 9
3 1 10
4 5 10
5 2 12
```

Now I want to apply some functions on the third columns of the rows that have a certain value in their second column. So for example I only want to consider the rows that have a `2` in their second column. And then I would like to have the mean, the median and the variance of 8,9,12.

In reality my matrix is larger but this is the basic idea. I guess I need a function that first checks the value in the second column and then considers only the values of the third column that correspond with the given value. I made something like this, but it works just for the mean and is actually a waste since that function is already built in R.

This is what that looked like:

```
average<- function(m){
  k=0
   for (i in 1:nrow(x)){
     if(x[i,2]==m){
       k = k + x[i,3]
     } else {NULL}
     amount <- sum(x[,2]==m)
  }
   av <- k/amount
  return(av)}
```

Comment: Could you convert to a data frame and then just use the `dplyr` functions?  There would be a few different options there...such as `filter()` or `group_by()` and `summarise()`.  Similarly, if you wanted to learn `data.table` it would be useful for your desired end result here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
mat <- matrix(c(1:5, 2,2,1,5,2, 8,9,10,10,12), ncol = 3)

mean(mat[, 3][which(mat[, 2] == 2)])
```

Working from the inside out, first identify the indices corresponding to which of the second columns = 2 `which(mat[, 2] == 2)`. Then, subset column 3 to those indices with `mat[, 3][...]`, finally take their `mean()`.

Comment: Nice, works perfect. Could you confirm that just changing `mean` to `var` would give me the variance?

Comment: Yes, changing `mean` to `var` would give you the variance for column 3 where column 2 == 2. However, by the sounds of your question, you might be better off putting everything in a `data.frame` (instead of a matrix) and then using packages such as `dplyr` to make quick work of these "filter" and "summary" functions.

Answer (score 0):

Something like `mean(subset(df,column2name==2)[,3])`?
Or `mean(df$column3name[df$column2name==2])`?

For pure matrix `mean(df[df[,2]==2,3])`.

Comment: not quite sure how that works with the column2name statement. I get an error that it cannot find that object.

Comment: @Mathbeginner column2name is the name of your second column, if no such name existst see edit.